# Javascript function not showing second form name

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have 2 forms with different ids, in javascript function I'm going to get form id in variable name, but in name variable only first forms id is going, not going form 2 id my code is.

**HTML**

```
<form name="form" id="filterMemberByFamNum" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Family Number</label> <input type="text" name="familyNumber" placeholder="Family Number" class="form-control">
  </div>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="filterMembers();return false;">Submit</button>
</form>

<form name="form" id="filterMemberByMemName" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Member Name</label> <input type="text" name="member" placeholder="Member Name" class="form-control">
  </div>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="filterMembers();return false;">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**JS**

```
function filterMembers() {
  //alert("Submitted");
  var str = $("form").serialize();
  var name = $(this.form).attr('id');

  console.log(name);

  $.post("model/handler.php?name=" + name + "&op=formSubmit", {
    'data': str
  }, function(data) {
    $('#members').html(data);
  }, "json");

  return false;
}
```

Any time output result in console tab is `filterMemberByFamNum` infact I'm submitting `filterMemberByMemName` form.

Please help me.

Comment: Why do your forms have the same `name`?

Comment: Do you know what `this.form` means and what it is supposed to do?

Answer (score 0):

Your javascript as written doesn't know how to differentiate between the 2 forms because you are calling `serialize()` on `$("form")` - you have 2 forms, so it's gonna pick the first it finds. That's just part of the problem. You have 2 forms with the same `name` attribute. Those should be unique.

Since you are already using jQuery, rewrite this as

```js
$(".form-horizontal").on( "submit", function( event ) {
  var str = $(this).serialize();
  var name = $(this).attr('id');
  console.log(name);
  $.post("model/handler.php?name="+name+"&op=formSubmit",
    {
        'data':str
    },function(data){
        $('#members').html(data);
    },"json");
  return false;
});
```

and remove the onclicks on the buttons. You'll actually need to also make the button `type="submit"` as well.

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/cwells/L51snt2z/)

Comment: Its refreshing my page. I dont want to refresh my page, i m using ajax and getting data from json.

Comment: It's possible your php is throwing errors, and you aren't handling them with your jquery. Be sure to read [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) to see how to handle errors.